# ANR caused by com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModules

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase inside my app with Facebook authentication. After the 3th restart of my app, it freezes and then shows an ANR (please see my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396811/loginactivty-with-firebase-facebook-authentication-not-responding-after-3th-re)). After some doing some research i found out that something is blocking the main thread. I have no clue why this is happening. The error below show up a couple of times when my app is running (my app does not freeze when this error appears). Does anyone have an idea?

I have included some info below, maybe it helps

Note: Google play services on test device (Samsung SM-G920F) is running version: 9.0.83 (440-121911109)

Getting this error:

```
05-28 02:35:56.798 29479-29506/? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.package.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

Theads:

[image]

Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-auth:1.0.0-beta12@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same ANR as you using Firebase and Google Play Services.  I solved my problem with the answer in [After Upgrading to Google Play Services 9.0.0, App Hangs in DynamiteModulesC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357974/after-upgrading-to-google-play-services-9-0-0-app-hangs-in-dynamitemodulesc) -- remove the general play-services and only include the specific play service libraries you need.